# Get updated data from database with reactjs, axios and php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ajax, axios

I want to get the latest data from a database and render it to my page.
When i load the page for the first time it works fine, but when i change data in the db nothing changes on the page. Even when i call the update function it does not change anything.

The page im posting to has a php function which retrieves data from the db (mysql).

If im doing something wrong, what would be my best option for this?

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {resultState: "red"};
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(`https://web.site/page.php`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({ resultState: res.data });
    });
  }
  
  update() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  };
  render() {
    return (<div>
        <div className="row" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.resultState}}></div>
        </div>)
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

Comment: Dont think its a catch problem as im using post method

Comment: Consider using websockets or server sent events instead of ajax if you want to get real time updates from server. Research *"ajax long polling vs websockets"*

Comment: @charlietfl The update to the db will always be done by the user (usually through jQuery ajax), so i just need it to update when state change or the update function is called

Comment: @charlietfl As of now it would even work that it should update when the user clicks update (which triggers the update function...)

Comment: Ok...simple fix is move the axios to `update()` or call it something like `getData()` and call that also in `componentDidMount()`. A component only mounts once but can re-render infinite times which is why forceUpdate not doing what you want

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your code works only if you refresh your page.

A simple solution would be pooling the PHP server. Create a load function whose job is to call the PHP server and in your ComponentDidMount function do the following updates

```
load() {
    axios.post(`https://web.site/page.php`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      // compare if the data has new values
      // if it has then update the state i.e. this.setState({ resultState: res.data });
      // otherwise do nothing
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
    // This will call the PHP server every 1 minute
    setTimeout(this.load(), 1000);
}
```

Do not use `this.forceUpdate();` as it's not recommended by the react team to be used.

Comment: Thanks. Will this call a mysql script every minute (the script thats on https://web.site/page.php)?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to how often you want that script to be called.